# script in xcode to change values at build time

Tags: ios, xcode

I have source code of app iOS project. I want make it multiple branded app. For e.g. I want to change the value of a Variable, app icon, bundle identifier, display name at build time.

How can i do this?

Comment: Or you can use **xcconfig**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create multiple schemes like we have default debug/release in xcode project to have as a brand type.
[multiple schemes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z5VK.png)

Add User-defined variables in build setting.Then you can change values in schemes.See screenshots for example.
[user defined variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6JhI.png)

> OR 
>   Simply create multiple targets having different icon images & display name.